# Can I add a macro to change the value of a cell in sheet 2 based on increasing the value of a cell in sheet 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm trying to design a macro that will change all cells in a row with a value of 4 to a value of 3. But only if I update a cell on another sheet.

Can this be done?
Is it also possible to do this in one formula but across multiple rows?

I need to do this to update a training matrix. So that when I update an SOP number in sheet 1 it will change everyone on code 4 (currently trained) to code 3 (trained to previous version). As I have hundreds of rows of SOPs I don't want to have to have a different code for each row.

Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Sir Adelaide, Can you please tell me how?

Comment: @Steve this is not a script writing service. Please give it a try and come back with an edit to your question (or ask a new question if this is closed) to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: You mean to say if in a cell of Sheet 1 you type SOP number in few rows of Sheet 2 should have update with 3, write?

Comment: @RajeshS - a few columns in a row would need to change from 4 to 3. But only if current value is 4. But would need this to apply to multiple rows. Only updating columns in that row

Comment: @Steve, I've placed value randomly, You put 4 in any row, like A350:E351, this macro will replace it also. The reason is that, it searches the value written in cell G350 across the range(whatever is been selected for first prompted input box) & replaces it with value written in cell H350. So, you put the values as you need & run the Macro.

Comment: @RajeshS I have made an effort at adjusted the code and have something that works. I'm Stuck in adjusting this to work across multiple row. But only to update one row. Hopefully the code makes clear what I want to do. I can get the code to update multiple rows but this is no good. Please help

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose  I have made an effort at adjusted the code and have something that works. I'm Stuck in adjusting this to work across multiple row. But only to update one row. Hopefully the code makes clear what I want to do. I can get the code to update multiple rows but this is no good. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check the Screen Shot:**

[image]

*Insert below written VBA code as module in Sheet 2:*

```
Sub MultiFindReplace()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
xTitleId = "Find & Replace"

Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
If Sheet1.Range("A208").value = "OTP" Then

    InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).value
End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

1. Run this Macro, in the first popped out prompt box, specify the data
   range that you want to be replaced the 4 with 3.
2. For the shown example select A350:E352.
3. Click OK, another prompt box is displayed to remind you select the
   criteria (Find & Replace Value Range).
4. For shown example select G350:H350.
5. Finish with OK, you find all the 4s have been replaced with 3s as you need.

**N.B.**

1. For the first pooped prompt box you may either select the entire
   range (as I've shown in example) or any of the Columns where you want
   to replace 4 with 3.
2. Don't forget to write "OTP" in **Cell A208 of Sheet 1** before you Run
   this Macro.
3. You must write *4 in G350 & 3 in H350.*
4. You can adjust the Cell address as well as value in A208(Sheet1) according 
   to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I've got something that works by editing the solution posted above.

I have this in sheet1(code)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$3" Then
Call MultiFindReplace
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
Call MultiFindReplace2
End If

End Sub
```

And I have this on Module1(code)

```
Sub MultiFindReplace()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range

For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Set InputRng = Worksheet.Range("D4:S4")
Set ReplaceRng = Worksheet.Range("D4:S4")
    InputRng.Replace what:=(4), replacement:=(3)

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub MultiFindReplace2()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range

For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Set InputRng = Worksheet.Range("D5:S5")
Set ReplaceRng = Worksheet.Range("D5:S5")
    InputRng.Replace what:=(4), replacement:=(3)

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is there a smarter way of writing this so that I don't have hundreds of different calls?